# Conditional Probability with binary variables

Tags: r, probability, probability-theory

I have this set:

```
    1 2 3 4
r01 1 0 1 1
r02 1 1 0 1
r03 0 0 1 0
r04 0 0 1 0
```

The code:

```
initial <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,0), c(0,1,0,0), c(1,0,1,1),c(1,1,0,0), row.names = c("r01","r02","r03","r04"))
colnames(initial) <- c(1:4)
```

I need to get conditional probability, for example if I choose `r03` as choosen object probability conditional table with `r01` will be:

```
          |r03=0 |r03=1
    r01=0 | 1/3  | 0/1
    r01=1 | 2/3  | 1/1
```

Other example, if I choose `r03` and evaluate `r02`:

```
          |r03=0 |r03=1
    r02=0 | 0/3  | 1/1
    r02=1 | 3/3  | 0/1
```

I don't know how to implement this table or just get this matrix values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for this:

```
initial <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,0), c(0,1,0,0), c(1,0,1,1),c(1,1,0,0), row.names = c("r01","r02","r03","r04"))
colnames(initial) <- c(1:4)

tin <- data.frame(matrix(t(initial), ncol = 4, byrow = FALSE))
colnames(tin) <- rownames(initial)

tab <- table(tin$r01, tin$r03) #here specify values and get count
prop.table(tab,2)
```

You also can add some `rownames` i `colnames`

EDIT: 
Fixed probability and created matrix by columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's correct? I checked it and for r03 = 0 and r01 = 0 I get 0 and the correct value is 1/3=0,333...